# How to Invoke WebView Extension from File Type

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VS Code WebView extension that I wish to invoke/trigger when I open a file of a specific file extension name.  e.g.  `MyFile.abc`.

Within myExt I added the `onFileSystem` to the `activationEvents` within `package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "myext",
    "description": "A Webview API Sample",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "publisher": "vscode-myext",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.25.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "onWebviewPanel:myExt",
        "onFileSystem:abc",
        "*"     
    ],
    "main": "./out/extension.js",
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "myExt.start",
                "title": "Start myExt ",
                "category": "My Ext"
            }
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "tsc -p ./",
        "compile": "tsc -p ./",
        "watch": "tsc -w -p ./",
        "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "supports-color": "^6.0.0",
        "vscode": "^1.1.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^10.5.2",
        "tslint": "^5.11.0",
        "typescript": "^2.9.2"
    }
}
```

When I add `"onFileSystem:abc"` to `activationEvents` in myExt I was expecting my webview extension to open anytime I opened a file with the extension `.abc` however nothing happened.

I then tried the activationEvents setting `"*"`, expecting that my webview extension would open at the start of VSCode but that too did not open my extension.

I am able to open and run my extension through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> as per normal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any [activation event](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events) that fires when a file with a specific name or extension is opened. The [`onFileSystem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#onFileSystem) event you were trying has a different purpose and checks for the *scheme* of a file.

Normally you would use `onLanguage` for this, and use the language identifier that your `.abc` extension is associated with. If it's not a popular file extension, you might need to register it in the [`contributes.languages` section](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.languages).

> I then tried the `activationEvents` setting `"*"`, expecting that my webview extension would open at the start of VSCode but that too did not open my extension.

The `activate()` method of your extension should always be called if the activation event is `*`. I assume by "running it with the command palette" you mean debugging the extension through the extension development host? Unless your extension is in your `<User>/.vscode/extensions` directory, it wouldn't be included in regular VSCode executions. It should then also be listed in the Extensions panel.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use

"workspaceContains:*.abc" as activationEvents

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do something for below in package.json

```
{
"activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:"**HERE WILL BE YOUR EXTENSION NAME WHICH YOU REGISTERED**"    
    ],
  "contributes": {

    "menus": {
      "explorer/context": [
        {
          "when": "resourceLangId == **abc**",  // this is the extension of the file where you want to execute your command
          "command": "**YOUR COMMAND NAME**",
          "title": "Anything relevent title",
          "group": "navigation"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [custom-editor-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/custom-editor-sample) example by Microsoft, you need to do the following configuration in package.json:

```
    "contributes": {
    "customEditors": [
        {
            "viewType": "catCustoms.catScratch",
            "displayName": "Cat Scratch",
            "selector": [
                {
                    "filenamePattern": "*.cscratch"
                }
            ]
        },
```